# Issue when trying to use jQuery's window.open function in combination with a for-loop to iterate through an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have an array of links like this:

```
var playlist = [
    "",
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com",
    "https://www.instagram.com"
];
```

And a bunch of boxes generated in the following way:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".container").append("<div class='luke luke-" + i + "'>" + "<h3 class='nummer'>Luke " + i + "</h3> " + "</div>");
}
```

I then want to iterate through this array to open a specific link when a box is clicked.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".luke-" + i).click(function(){
        window.open(playlist[i], "_blank");
    })
}
```

That doesn't seem to work at all, however the example below does exactly what I want.

```
$(".luke-1").click(function(){
    window.open(playlist[1], "_blank");
})
$(".luke-2").click(function(){
    window.open(playlist[2], "_blank");
})
$(".luke-3").click(function(){
    window.open(playlist[3], "_blank");
})
$(".luke-4").click(function(){
    window.open(playlist[4], "_blank");
})
$(".luke-5").click(function(){
    window.open(playlist[5], "_blank");
})
```

So this works, but it's a pain in the ass to setup as I want to have 25 boxes in total and this solution offers little to no flexibility if I want to increase or decrease that amount at a later time. What am I doing wrong with the for-loop that's causing issues here?

If I use

```
console.log(playlist[i]);
```

inside of the for-loop, it simply returns "undefined" regardless of what box I click in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing right.

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dktv4bjj/)

```
var playlist = [
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com",
    "https://www.instagram.com"
];
var container = $("#container");
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
 container.append('<div class="luke" db-id="'+ i + '"><h3 class="nummer">Luke ' + i + '</h3></div>'); 
}

$(".luke").click(function(i){
  window.open(playlist[$(this).attr('db-id')], "_blank");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".luke-" + i).click(function(i){
        window.open(playlist[i], "_blank");
    })
}
```

The `click` event will launch your function only inside the scope of the loop. This means that once the loop have finished, ( and counting from 0 to 5 is insanely fast for your computer ) there's no more function attached to your click event. In other terms, as long as `i < 5`, your click function will work as you expect, but after that, the `click` event will no longer call the function you created.

One solution could to be attach a function to the `onclick` attribute in the HTML like this :

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   $('<div/>', {
     'class': 'luke luke-' + i,
     'click': yourFunction(i)
   }).appendTo(${'.container'});

   $('<h3/>', {
      'class':'nummer',
      'html': 'Luke' + i
    }).appendTo(${'.luke-'+i})

}
```

and then write a function like this :

```
function yourFunction(index){
   window.open(playlist[index], "_blank");
}
```

Comment: appendTo(${'.container'}); This line is giving me an error, but I changed it to .appendTo('.container'); and the solution now works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much easier and simpler using a data attribute.

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
var playlist = [
    "",
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com",
    "https://www.instagram.com"
];

for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".container").append("<div class='luke' data-url='" + playlist[i] + "'>" + "<h3 class='nummer'>Luke " + i + "</h3> " + "</div>");
}

$('.luke').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).data('url'));
});
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rv0Lp879/1/)

Comment: That's a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way by using Hyperlink

```
hyperlinks
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/amitdodake/nzph1qm0/)

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the idea is to have the whole area be clickable. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it!